# How do I create a two pane application having a slideout menu with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: master-detail, xamarin.forms

I was think that I could put a MasterDetailPage in the Detail of a MasterDetailPage where the outer MasterDetailPage would provide the slide out menu and the inner MasterDetailPage would always have both the Master and Detail visible.  When I tried this the slide out menu of the outer Master did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The inner page probably cannot be a master detail page.  Instead your options are:

- Create the inner page as a single page using Views in Grids and swap the second column view programatically for your navigation
- Stick with a MasterDetailPage within the detail of your outer master detail page but completely swap out your inner master detail page rendering (by subclassing the MasterDetailPage to something like 'AlwaysOpenMasterDetail' and registering a custom renderer against it).  In the custom renderer instead of relying on the TabletMasterDetailPageRenderer that Xamarin provide, create your own IVisualElementRenderer that uses RenderFactory.GetRenderer(page) to get UIViewControllers to add as your children (and position however you like).